# Kafka Consumer only reads after 'enough' data has been produced

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am implementing an endpoint in spring-boot that, when invoked, will do a dump of all the messages sitting in a kafka topic (for testing).

The behaviour I am expecting is that when a producer writes to the 'testTopic' topic, and subsequently the consumer polls, then it should read the message just produced.

The behaviour I am observing is that the consumer fails to consume the produced message. Further, if the producer produces a lot more messages (say 10-15), then the consumer will dump all of them in one go. From this point on, if the producer produces even one message, then the consumer will consume as expected.

Intuitively I thought that the setting `FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG` might have something to do with this - perhaps the consumer was waiting for enough bytes to be written. But this is already set to 1 byte (the default) and doesn't explain the subsequent successful individual message reads.

Next I thought that maybe I was registering the consumer before the topic was created (by calling the registering endpoint too quickly). But I confirmed from `kafka-topics.sh` that the topic exists before registering the consumer.

I noticed that if I enable autocommit of offsets, then the behaviour is sometimes as expected and sometimes not. With manually committing offsets (not shown in code below) the behaviour is very odd as described above.

I also know the producer is working as expected by confirming it using `kafka-console-consumer`.

Also tried increasing the polling timeout to 1 second but no luck.

```
// Consumer
@Component
public class TestConsumer{
    private KafkaConsumer testConsumer = null;

    public void registerConsumer(final String consumerId) {
        if (consumer == null) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "<some_address>:<some_port>");
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "testGroup");

            testConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
            testConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("testTopic"));
        }
        else{
            logger.debug("Consumer already registered");
        }
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> consume() {
        Map<String, List<String>> messages = new HashMap<>();
        if (testConsumer == null){
            logger.error("testConsumer was not instantiated");
            return null;
        }
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = testConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record: records){
            logger.debug(String.format("Consuming %s", record.value()));
            buffer.add(record.value());
        }
        messages.put("data", buffer);
        return messages;
    }
}
```

The sequence of steps is:
1. spring boot application launches
2. the kafka topic is created, I can confirm via the kafka console
3. I register the producer and consumer
4. Producer produces and I can confirm this with the kafka console (different consumer group)
5. Consumer fails to consume

I am expecting the result to be as follows:

```
{
    "data" : ["message1"]
}
```

What I get is

```
{
    "data" : []
}
```

Any ideas why the consumer is not consuming records until a threshold number of messages have been written?

EDIT_1: 
Added the `props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");` property to the consumer without effect.

Comment: actually what os your question? consumer is not consuming records? or anything else?

Comment: @Deadpool The consumer is not consuming records until a threshold number of messages have been written. Why?

Comment: From where & how you are calling `consume()` method? 
`public Map<String, List<String>> consume() `

Comment: Show how you are producing data @jateeq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are manually invoking this `testConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100))`. You need to continuously pool from the topic. Like inside a infinite while loop. eg:

```
while (true) {
   Map records = consume();
   logger.debug("received records: {}", records);
}
```

Have a look at this link: [Kafka consumer](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

Comment: that seemed to be it. I didn't want to run in an infinite while loop because the consumer was meant to be for testing, so I thought I'd poll once and that'd be that. I settled for polling for a finite number of iterations. Thanks!